# Eclipse Job: How to manually call ISchedulingRule's isConflicting() method?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jobs, job-scheduling

I have multiple jobs and I set to them `ISchedulingRule` for not running more than 2 jobs at the same time.

I check and control `runningJobNumber` at the listener of jobManager's `done()` and `running()` methods. However, rule's `isConflicting()` method is always called before `done()` method of `JobManager's listener`.

So, because of that state, next job is waiting for next call of `isConflicting()` and I want to manually call `isConflicting()` from `JobListener's done()` method().

Here is my code sample:

```
Job.getJobManager().addJobChangeListener(new IJobChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void sleeping(IJobChangeEvent event) {
    }

    @Override
    public void scheduled(IJobChangeEvent event) {

    }

    @Override
    public void running(IJobChangeEvent event) {
        if (event.getJob() instanceof MyJob) {
            numRunningJobs.incrementAndGet();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void done(IJobChangeEvent event) {
        if (event.getJob() instanceof MyJob) {
            numRunningJobs.decrementAndGet();
            System.out.println("done is called: " + System.currentTimeMillis());                    
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void awake(IJobChangeEvent event) {

    }

    @Override
    public void aboutToRun(IJobChangeEvent event) {

    }
});

public class MySchedulingRule implements ISchedulingRule {

    public MySchedulingRule() {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(final ISchedulingRule rule) {
        if (rule == this) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isConflicting(final ISchedulingRule rule) {

        if (rule == this) {
            return true;
        }

        if (rule instanceof MySchedulingRule) {
            System.out.println("isConflicting is called: " + System.currentTimeMillis());

            boolean result = Activator.getDefault().getNumRunningJobs() >= 2;
            System.out.println("Conflicted: " + result);
            return result;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to show us some code to help us understand the issue.

Comment: @greg-449 added my sample code